# Creating timestamp for 5/13/2014 @ 3pm

Tags: php, datetime

I have an application that needs to send a UTC timestamp in order for it to work correctly. In my application a user can have any number of timezones. So if they pick 3pm and their timezone is America/New_York, it is a different 3pm than if it was America/Chicago.

I need to figure out a way to change the date into the right UTC timestamp. I know I can use date_default_timezone_set("UTC")...but I don't think will work correctly.

I think I need to calculate a difference between UTC and regular timezone, but I am not sure. Any advice is welcomes.

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo strtotime('5/13/2014 3:00 PM');
```

1399993200

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
echo strtotime('5/13/2014 3:00 PM');
```

1400007600

As you can tell these 2 values are different.

EDIT: Here is what my code looks like. It doesn't seem to work correctly as the application doesn't show the event in the right time.

```
$previous_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$aceroute_schedule = $this->sale_lib->get_send_to_aceroute_schedule();

if (($start_time = strtotime($aceroute_schedule['aceroute_schedule_date']. ' '.$aceroute_schedule['aceroute_schedule_time_start'])) !== FALSE)
{
    //Append 000 as as string for 32 bit systems
    $start_epoch = $start_time.'000';
    $end_epoch = strtotime('+ '.$aceroute_schedule['aceroute_duration'].' minutes', $start_time).'000';
}
else //Default to current time + 1 hour
{
        //Append 000 as as string for 32 bit systems
        $start_epoch = time().'000';
        $end_epoch = strtotime('+1 hour', time()).'000';
}

$event->start_epoch = $start_epoch;
$event->end_epoch = $end_epoch;
```

Comment: Timestamps are always timezone-agnostic -- they refer to a moment in time, irrespective of what the wall clock time happens to be in your part of the world at that moment. I'm not sure if you have things neatly organized in your head, and can't quite understand what the question is. Can you express it more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

This will now create a `DateTime` object in the user's `DateTimeZone` ('America/New_York').  And then it will set that object's timezone to UTC.  To get the timestamp (or other string representations of date), use [`::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

```
# Create NY date
$NY = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$NYdate = new DateTime('5/13/2014 3:00 PM', $NY);

# Set timezone to UTC
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$UTCdate = $NYdate->setTimezone($UTC);

# Get timestamp (PHP 5.2 compatible)
$timezone = $UTCdate->format('U');
var_dump($timezone); // a string containing UNIX timestamp
```

---

First I create 2 `DateTime` objects based off of their respective `DateTimeZone` objects.  Then we can either use OOP [`::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to get another object containing information about the time difference. Or we can use simple integers representing the difference in seconds from [`::getTimestamp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

```
$date = '5/13/2014 3:00 PM';

# Create NY date
$NY = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$NYdate = new DateTime($date, $NY);

# Create UTC date
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$UTCdate = new DateTime($date, $UTC);

# Find difference object
$diff = $NYdate->diff($UTCdate);
var_dump($diff); // a DateInterval object containing time difference info

# Find difference in seconds
$diff = $NYdate->getTimestamp() - $UTCdate->getTimestamp();
var_dump($diff); // an integer containing time difference in seconds
```

---

**Links:**

- [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)
- [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Comment: I need to support php 5.2 and getTimestamp is only 5.3 or newer. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: [`$NYDate->format('U');`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) -- [`U`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is the PHP Date format for timestamp.

Comment: Also, I updated the question with my code. I think you showed me how to get the difference, but I need to send a UTC time to the application.

Comment: I see that yours is working correctly. I don't understand why mine didn't work (In original question). Is it because I am starting the date using UTC even though it is NOT a utc date? Is the idea to save the date in current timezone, then switch the timezone.

Comment: Yea, UNIX timestamps are the seconds from the UNIX Epoch (GMT).  So you were just getting a generic time for either `UTC` or `America/New_York`.  Now, you are creating a time specific to `America/New_York` and converting it to `UTC`.  Then you can do whatever you want with it.  I bet it could be done the way you were headed, but my example is much more structured and the OOP helps visualize what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Example in http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

The first line creates a `DateTIme` object, using the timezone `Pacific/Nauru`.

You can then change the timezone using `setTimezone` as shown in line 4, and the output will be modified accordingly.

note: the default timezone (if you don't specify it in the 2nd parameter in line 1) is the one set in your `php.ini` file, which you can modify (at runtime) with `date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York")`

note2: the 1st parameter in line 1, is equivalent to the 1st parameter of the `strtotime` function.

note3: the `format` method takes the same format parameter as `date` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)